# Request header field authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response

Tags: angular, angularjs, cors

I am using geoapify to generate address from latitude and longitude. Api Is working fine in
postman, but when I am using it into my app. It is giving be cors policy error when I login into my website and without login it is also working fine in my app too.
I have found my similar question but most of them are using backend api not any 3rd party api.But after reading so many question I found that adding Authorization token in header my may work. but it didn't worked. Anyone can please what should i do in my case.

gymservice.ts

```
getaddress(lat:any,long:any){
   
      return this.http.get(`https://api.geoapify.com/v1/geocode/reverse?lat=${lat}&lon=${long}&apiKey=myapikey`);
  }
```

gymlist.ts

```
generateAddress(latitude:any,longitude:any){
       this.toolservice.getaddress(latitude,longitude).subscribe((res:any)=>{
            this.userState = res.features[0].properties.state;
            this.userCity = res.features[0].properties.state_district;
            console.log(this.userCity);
            console.log(this.userState);
            this.getGymByStateCity();
       });
  }
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why do you need to add an `Authorization` header to your request? If I understand [Geoapify's documentation](https://apidocs.geoapify.com/docs/geocoding/forward-geocoding/) properly, you're supposed to specify the API key in a URL query parameter named `apiKey`.

Comment: @jub0bs I found Authorization header in some question i.e. why i am adding it still it is giving me cors policy error with auth or without. and i am specify api key. if you can check my code!

Comment: I'm telling you to _remove_ that `Authorization` header from your request. That header name is not allowed by Geoapify's CORS policy. If you're updated your code, update your question accordingly.

Comment: Say I have a server abc.com and I don't want you to get any information from it, so before I give the response, I will check if the url starts with abc.com, otherwise, I will reject it. I hope that helps you understand what cors means, it means to help the owner protect their website resources. That's the reason why it mostly related to backend. What you can do from frontend is to create your own server - same as postman, server isn't restricted by cors. Or check if the website provides any api to interact with it. If none is available, you simple can't have permission to access the site.

Comment: @jub0bs Okay!,I removed it stil giving same error. I have updated my code too!

Comment: @Jimmy I got your point. But the thing is on website I am getting response when logout from website but when I login it is giving me cors policy error. And can elaborate more how to create own server from front-end. I beginner in front-end. I didn't got that point.

Comment: @NitinSaini Are you sure? If you've removed the `Authorization` header from your request, you should no longer be getting the same error message as before. Can you post a screenshot of your browser's Network tab showing the problematic GET request?

Comment: @jub0bs added you can check now

Comment: And what is the source for that `http.get` function? That has to be the culprit.

Comment: It is in angular to fetch data from api. I don't think http.get doing something wrong. Well what You suggest then?